# InfluxDB write event listener/trigger

Tags: javascript, statistics, real-time, influxdb

Reading through documentation as well as other SO posts did not help me find out either `InfluxDB` supports event listeners/triggers on write operations or not. Because it's meant for real-time analytics, I would like to be notified when a specific point gets inserted in a specific series. I know I could use `Continuous Queries` but in some cases when data is inserted at much lower, non-constant rates, running `CQs` on non-changed queries become useless.

The perfect scenario would be to use some event listeners/triggers and query the data when it changes. Does `InfluxDB` supports it or I have to implement this feature manually?

Answer (score 4):

Influxdb supports HTTP/HTTPs and UDP subscriptions. Subscribers receive a copy of any new data written to influxdb, and can do what they wish with that data. This is how Kapacitor (referenced in other answers) works.

You can learn more about subscriptions [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/subscription-management/)

Depending on your needs it may be easier to use Kapacitor or code your own subscriber, though I haven't found documentation regarding the subscription APIs.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like something you could use InfluxData's [Kapacitor](https://influxdata.com/time-series-platform/kapacitor/) for. It's one of their newer products.

> Kapacitor is a data processing engine. It can process both stream (subscribe realtime) and batch (bulk query) data from InfluxDB. Kapacitor lets you define custom logic to process alerts with dynamic thresholds, match metrics for patterns, compute statistical anomalies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB does not have any triggers or alerting as part of the database. It's a clear need for the community and InfluxData is working on ways to address the need, but they are not yet available.

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know. I'll try to implement my custom websocket emiters to see if it fits my needs.

Comment: [Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) is a new part of the InfluxData stack that handles stream processing and alerting.